# No Deploy option IIS

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I've been looking at MSDeploy recently, specifically this presentation here.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

Everything has been going fine till now except I'm trying to find the Deploy/Export Applications within IIS and they don't seem to be present.

I'm presuming there needs to be some option turned on so I can see them but I'm damned if I know what.

I have got the web deployment tool installed

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was something wrong with my setup. I unistalled MSDeply and installed again using the web platform installer and everything was happy

Comment: "Web Deployment Tool" in the program list and web pi short cut link: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=Wdeploy